# Proper keyboard typing event handling in input element using require.js and jQuery $(document).ready()

Tags: jquery, input, keyboard-events, jquery-events

I've got this code before `</body>`:

```
<script>
    require(['lvrg', 'jquery', 'jquery.i18n', 'purl'], function (lvrg, $) {
      $('#sidebar-wrapper').load('/menu');
      $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
      });
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var menuOptions = $('a.menu-option');
        console.log("menuOptions:", menuOptions);
        $('input#search-option').on('keydown', function(e) {
          console.log('e:', e);
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

And this `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for option" name="search-bar" id="search-option">` in DOM.

The problem is, this fragment doesn't work at all:
`$('input#search-option').on('keydown', function(e) {console.log('e:', e);});`
and I don't know why.

When the document is ready, there's **menuOptions** seen in console, with all it's values.

Keyboard input event handling doesn't work even when I change method from `on()` to `keypress()`, `keyup()` or `keydown()`.

But when I paste some code for keyboard event handling i.e. `$('input#search-option').on('keyup', function(e) {console.log('e:', e);});` into devtools console and hit enter, while being on the website, the code really handles the input, because I can see this in console `e: m.Event {originalEvent: KeyboardEvent, type: "keyup", timeStamp: 1447074756199, jQuery11130594990452285856: true, keyCode: 53…} VM4184:2`

I'm testing this code on Opera 33.0.1990.58, but same effect I'm getting on Firefox 42 and IE 11. I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Anybody has idea why this isn't working as supposed?

Comment: You're using two different selectors; `a.menu-option` and `input#search-option`. From your debugging, it seems that `input#search-option` isn't in the DOM on ready, but `a.menu-option` is. Try `$(document).on('keydown', 'input#search-option', function () { /**/ })`.

Comment: And the scripts I've got in `<head>` are: squel-4.2.1.min.js, http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js, jquery.i18n-1.0.3.js, purl-2.3.1.js, moment-2.10.6.min.js, underscore-1.8.3-min.js, jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js, select2-3.5.4.min.js and bootstrap-3.3.5.min.js

Comment: @Matt elements related to both selectors are in DOM loaded. They're seen in view in browser, they're seen also in **Elements** in devtools.
I'll try your recommendation and answer whether it worked or not.

Comment: Ok, so used this code `$(this).on('keypress', 'input#search-term', function(e) {console.log('e:', e);});` instead of `$('input#search-option').on('keydown', function(e) {console.log('e:', e);});` and tested it on Opera 33.0.1990.58, Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m (incognito window), Firefox 42 and IE 11 and **it worked, finally**!
But still don't know why earlier code didn't worked..
Anyway thank you very much @Matt without your help it would take me a lot of time, to figure this out.
How you knew that I should bind `on()` event handler to `$(document)` first?

Comment: spaffy: If an event handler isn't attaching itself, 99% of the cases are covered by 1) the selector has been mistyped, or 2) the element isn't in the DOM at the time `on()` was called. By using `$(document).on(...)`, you're attaching the event handler to `document` (which *always* exists) rather than a particular element; so it's a very quick/ reliable way of determining whether the problem *is* caused by the element being/ not being in the DOM or not.